# Bamboo error - ImportError: no module named pandas

Tags: python, bamboo

I have created a Bamboo task which runs the python code from a BitBucket Repo.

Bamboo config:
I am running the script as a `file`. 
I have selected interpreter as `Shell` and given this in the Script Body to execute the script `python create_issue.py -c conf.yml`

After I click on 'Run Plan', the build fails with ImportError: No module named pandas. The rest of the libraries are working fine, like, `requests`, `itertools`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are running this Bamboo plan using the Agent Host and not a Docker Container.  As such you will need to:

1. Remote/Log into the Bamboo server
2. Use pip or some other package tool to install requests, itertools, and any other missing imports

Alternatively, you could set-up an isolated Docker image that has all these dependencies and build within that.

Comment: Hi @Wesley, thanks for your answer. I will google into how to set up a docker file. Since I am new to this can you help me with providing some useful links?

Comment: To clarify the answer, it would be easier to just log into the Bamboo server and install these python packages.  If you want to go the Docker approach Atlassian has a good getting started guide: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/docker-runner-946020207.html

Comment: Thanks very much.